# Как правильно: привлекли или привлек? Отец с сыном или отец и сын?

Tags: выбор-слов

*Мое внимание привлек**ли** отец **с** сын**ом**.*

*Мое внимание привл**ек** отец **и** сы**н**.*

*Мое внимание привлек**ли** отец **и** сы**н**.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

*Рядом со мной расположилась семья приезжих. Отец с сыном (отец и сын) **привлекли** мое внимание.*

В данном случае нельзя использовать форму ед. числа, так как **действие субъектов равноправное.**

Это действие является пассивным, так как по смыслу это автор обращает внимание на отца с сыном (на отца и сына).

Розенталь:   §186. Сказуемое при подлежащем типа брат с сестрой.[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_04)

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**Зачем отвечать, если ответ уже дан?** Да, ответ правильный, но **мы же не оракулы.** К ответу должно прилагаться хотя бы какое-то объяснение.

Если сложно найти ссылку на правила, то можно написать, **что правильность ответа очевидна, что это можно определить на слух.** Тогда автору будет понятно, чем руководствовался отвечающий.

Answer (score 3):

Первый и третий варианты подойдут.